# How to fix 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte' when using Python C Extensions?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, encoding

Given the following file `bug.txt`:

```
event "øat" not handled
```

I wrote the following Python C Extensions on the file `fastfilewrapper.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

static PyObject* hello_world(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    std::string retval;
    std::ifstream fileifstream;

    fileifstream.open("./bug.txt");
    std::getline( fileifstream, retval );
    fileifstream.close();
    std::cout << "retval " << retval << std::endl;
    return Py_BuildValue( "s", retval.c_str() );
}

static PyMethodDef hello_methods[] = { {
        "hello_world", hello_world, METH_NOARGS,
        "Print 'hello world' from a method defined in a C extension."
    },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef hello_definition = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "hello", "A Python module that prints 'hello world' from C code.",
    -1, hello_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_fastfilepackage(void) {
    Py_Initialize();
    return PyModule_Create(&hello_definition);
}
```

I built it with `pip3 install .` using this `setup.py`

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

# https://bugs.python.org/issue35893
from distutils.command import build_ext

def get_export_symbols(self, ext):
    parts = ext.name.split(".")
    if parts[-1] == "__init__":
        initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + parts[-2]
    else:
        initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + parts[-1]

build_ext.build_ext.get_export_symbols = get_export_symbols

setup(name='fastfilepackage', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('fastfilepackage', ['fastfilewrapper.cpp'])])
```

Then, I use this `test.py` script:

```py
import fastfilepackage

iterable = fastfilepackage.hello_world()
print('iterable', iterable)
```

But Python throws this exception when I run the `test.py` Python Script:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python3 test.py
Hello, world!
retval event "▒at" not handled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    iterable = fastfilepackage.hello_world()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

How can I recover from invalid Unicode characters?

i.e., ignore these errors when binding C and Python.

When purely working with Python, I can use this:

```py
file_in = open( './bug.txt', errors='replace' )
line = file_in.read()
print( "The input line was: {line}".format(line=line) )
```

What is the equivalent to `errors='replace'` when binding with `Python C Extensions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 'replace' error handling semantic you should do it on the C side like so and return it to the python side:

```
return PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8(retval.c_str(), retval.size(), "replace");
```

This will give in our case sth like:

```
Hello, world!
retval event "?at" not handled
iterable event "�at" not handled
```

Comment: `retval` (std::string) has a member called `size()` which has constant complexity O(1), then, there is no need to use `strlen(str)` with complexity O(n).

Comment: `retval.c_str()` also has constant complexity O(1) (C++ 11 and later), so there is no need to allocate a `char*` to store its value. The fix would just be replace the line `return Py_BuildValue( "s", retval.c_str() );` with  `return PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8(retval.c_str(), retval.size(), , "replace");` as `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` already returns a `PyObject *` and that is exacly what I need to return from `hello_world`.

Comment: I have updated the answer as it is now (after the removal of strlen) a more concise solution.
Regarding the assignment `const char *cStr = retval.c_str();`: There is no dynamically memory allocation for the string value, but only the pointer to the string is simply assigned to a variable, which is negligible in terms of performance in any case.