# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 6208: invalid start byte (Python C-Extension)

Tags: python-3.x, pjsip, python-c-api

I am working with this [library](https://github.com/nicolaipre/python3-pjsip-memory-buffer), which is a fork of [pjsua](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/tree/master/pjsip-apps/src/python) with minor [modifications from here](https://github.com/UFAL-DSG/pjsip), to work with Python 3.

I have almost got everything working in the call and audio process, but I am running into an error related to the Python C-Extension (Python.h).

When attempting to fetch audio frames from the buffer, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/discord.py-1.3.0a1+g1b4124f-py3.7.egg/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "DiscordPhone.py", line 120, in on_message
    self.softphone.listen(self.call_audio) # listen to call, write to buffer call_audio
  File "/home/user/DiscordPhone/Softphone/Softphone.py", line 255, in listen
    data = mem_capture.get_frame() # frame.payload = raw pcm sample data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pjsuaxt.py", line 3072, in get_frame
    err, frame = _pjsuaxt.mem_capture_get_frame(self.port_id)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 6208: invalid start byte
mem_capture_cb - there is not enough space in the frame buffer
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error, since the error occurs on [line](https://github.com/nicolaipre/python3-pjsip-memory-buffer/blob/master/pjsuaxt.py#L3072): 
`err, frame = _pjsuaxt.mem_capture_get_frame(self.port_id)`, which is [data returned from a C function](https://github.com/nicolaipre/python3-pjsip-memory-buffer/blob/master/_pjsuaxt.c#L555).

If the implementation was pure Python, I could use a bytearray and append to that, but that is not possible here it seems...

The usage of [Py_BuildValue()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) also seems correct.

[I found a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204956/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-when-using-pyth), but I am not sure if applying the fix suggested would be the correct approach in this case, since UFAL-DSG did not seem to have the same problem when using their fork.

Comment: It looks like something (probably an output) is being stored as `str` which should be stored as `bytes`.

Comment: I'd think it'll be `PyObject *pFrame = PyUnicode_FromPJ(&frame);` - check the output to see if it's NULL

Comment: @DavidW. I agree, and I think so too. Python interprets the return value as a string, and attempts to utf-8 decode it, while C returns bytes. Also, I had forgotten to include the link to a similar issue on SO. I have updated the post to include the link.

Comment: My view is that the fix there isn't appropriate - I doubt if you want to ignore data that can't be interpreted as a unicode `str` (because in the context of audio, who cares if the data happens to be valid unicode or not). I think that this library should be returning a bytes object (i.e. you need to write `PyUnicode_FromPJ`)

Comment: @DavidW, I did some debugging. It seems that pFrame is 0 when I printed it before the return - like you thought.  

I also tried to change the return of Py_BuildValue to "cO" instead of "iO".